# How to join a large number of data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have 35 table (stocks) in the same format which has 2 columns: ["Trading_date","volume"].How can I join ALL of them using Pandas python to have the joined table in this format: ["Trading_date","volume_1","volume_2",...,"volume_35"] and keep all but remove duplicate of "Trading_date".
For example: table 1 has 5 rows, table 2 has 7 rows, two table share 4 rows on "Trading_date".  The joined of two tables will have 8 rows, the missing values in row["volume"] will be assign 0 or null (prefer 0)
Thank you very much for help.

Comment: You should edit your question to be nicer...

Comment: I check all type of join, and neither of them work for my case. Any suggestion for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
tables = [...] # your tables...
for i, tab in enumerate(tables):
    try: merged = pd.merge(merged, tab, how='left', on ='Trading_date', suffixes=('', '_%s'%(i)))
    except: merged = tab
```

Comment: see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Dror Hilman:  I edited the questions carefully . Please help me again. Left join keeps rows in the left dataframe